# How to exchange (remove and add) markers in Android GoogleMaps v2 while maintaining their click-ability

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

When the user touches a marker I want for some reason to exchange that marker (by using another graphic). Unfortunately Android GoogleMaps v2 does show up a strange behavior when I install the following (experimental) `onMarkerClick` handler:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    LatLng p = marker.getPosition();
    marker.remove();
    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p).title("new"));
    m.showInfoWindow();
    return true;
}
```

Observations:

- the first click (onto the "original" marker) calls the event handler, exchanges the marker and shows the info window correctly
- the second click (onto "new" marker) does not fire neither `onMapClick` nor `onMarkerClick`. Additionally the info window disappears (unexpected behavior)
- as all following clicks onto the same marker do not fire any event handler, the info window remains hidden until the user touches a free space on the map and then touches the marker again. Again, the marker is swapped and the info window appears but all consecutive clicks onto the marker are ignored as mentioned before.

Can anybody confirm this behavior? I do see it as a bug. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Filed as a bug: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5115

Answer (score 0):

Workaround copied from gmaps-api-issues:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    LatLng p = marker.getPosition();
    marker.remove();
    final Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p).title("new"));
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m.showInfoWindow();
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

where handler is defined as:

`private Handler handler = new Handler();`